# Powershell - Passing Array Value as a Parameter

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

Powershell novice here. Trying to find out why the $_ value can't be used in my expression:

```
$ServerList = @(
'Server1',
'Server2',
'Server3'
)

$ServerList | ForEach-Object (get-cswindowsservice -Name "rtcpdpcore" -Computer $_ | Select-object @{Label = "ServerName";Expression={$_}}, Status, Displayname | format-table -autosize -wrap)
```

Getting error:
Get-CsWindowsService : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument
is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command
again.

But THIS does output the array values fine??

```
$ServerList = @(
'Server1',
'Server2',
'Server3'
)

$ServerList | ForEach-Object {write-output $_}
```

Why is '$_' null in the first example? But populated in the second?

Thanks

Comment: You are using wrong kind of parenthesis for the 1st example. It should be `{}` instead of `()`.

Comment: Thank You! So simple! That's working.

Comment: New problem now. The value being passed to my label 'ServerName', is "rtcpdpcore" and not the Array Value. Very odd.

Comment: New problem, new question.

Comment: WaitingForGuacamole - Nailed it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Having changed your brackets from `()` to `{}`, the problem you're having is that the scope of `$_` changes as it works through the pipeline, so `$_` on the `Select-Object` is the object that was passed by `Get-CSWindowsService`, not the `ForEach-Object`. Try a minor refactor:

```
$ServerList | `
  ForEach-Object {
    $serverName = $_
    Get-CSWindowsservice -Name "rtcpdpcore" -Computer $serverName | `
    Select-object @{Label = "ServerName";Expression={$serverName}}, Status, Displayname | `
    Format-Table -autosize -wrap
  }
```

Comment: Nice. The backticks are not needed after `|`. PowerShell automatically continues parsing on next line if no token follows on same line.